# Callback when Twitter Retweet

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-search

I am new to using twitter streaming api.

I want to allow users to tweet from my application a text . And then if some body retweets that, i want to get notified.

If there are thousands of users who tweeted from my app, i need to know if somebody retweeted for each of their tweet.

Do we need to do constantly search for each users tweet id using streaming api to see if there are any retweets. ?

For this to happen , should i user give permission for my twitter app so we can see if any retweets